# How to mock objects with constructors in Python3?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-3.x, mocking

I'm new to Python (I'm from Java) and I'm facing an issue in using mocks in Python3.2.

Here is the code:

```
import gzip    

class MyClass:

    _content = None

    _gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile

    def __init__(self, content):
        self._content = content

    def my_method(self):
        # Code ...
        gzipper = self._gzipfile(fileobj=data)
        return gzipper.read()


import unittest
from mockito import *

class MyClassTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def my_method_test(self):
        gzipfile = mock
        myclass = MyClass()
        myclass._gzipfile = mock
        myclass.my_method
```

I would like to unit test my method (I'm using the mockito lib for mocks). But when I execute the test, I receive this:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fileobj'
```

In this case I'm forced to call the GzipFile object with a named parameter.

Is there a nice way to mock this GzipFile object (and similar ones)?

Comment: Is '__init' a typo, or an actual mistake?

Comment: It is not a typo, the double underscore makes italic text, and I don't know how to escape them... So I cheated

Comment: Ah, well, in that case I suggest adding an initialiser that expects a 'fileobj' argument.

Comment: The underscores won't trigger italics in code blocks. (You can look at the preview while you're editing if you're not sure.) I removed the formatting hacks back so __init__ is used where it should be. Makes the question clearer.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using mockito instead of mock?

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` you are seeing is caused by the fact that you are assigning `myclass._gzipfile` to the `mockito.mock` class object.  So when `my_method` calls `_gzipfile` with the keyword argument `fileobj=data`, it is actually calling the `mockito.mock` class and thus invoking its `__init__` method which does not understand this argument.

Something like this should work.  It's still not an ideal unit test since it has a dependency on gzip.GzipFile, but it should help get you started.

```
import gzip

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, content, file):
        self._content = content
        self._gzipper = gzip.GzipFile(filename=file)
    def my_method(self):
        # Code ...
        return self._gzipper.read()

import unittest
from mockito import *

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.my_class = MyClass('some content', 'file')

    def test_my_method(self):
    self.my_class._gzipper = mock()
        when(self.my_class._gzipper).read().thenReturn('gzipper read return')
        data = self.my_class.my_method()
        self.assertEqual(data, 'gzipper read return')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```